# How can I determine if a weighed random function is working as expected?

Tags: probability, distributions

I am writing a series of program utilities which heavily utilize weighted random functions, where the user defines a probability density function as a piecewise curve with a series of `(x, y)` coordinates and gets back numbers which conform to that function. What I've been doing so far to verify the working of the program is to crudely output a large number of weighted random numbers, plot them on a histogram, and eyeball to see if the curve looks as expected. I would like to be able to verify this more thoroughly and automatically.

Given a piecewise probability distribution function and a significant number of sample points, how can I determine if the sample points reasonably fall within the function?

Comment: *How* the function is represented in a computer has no bearing on the methods available to test random number generation.  The familiar procedures will work: histograms, probability plots, chi-squared tests, and so forth.  The only challenges are technical: all of these require evaluation of the cumulative distribution function (and sometimes its inverse).  How you cope with those challenges might depend on the details.  For instance, some choices of curve families may enable explicit algebraic computation of the CDF. Others will force you to perform numerical integration.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up building an automated test to sample a large number of points, make a histogram, and compare the deviation from the ideal CDF expectation within a somewhat forgiving margin.